# Code for deleting particular mails in G mail

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to write the code for below task:

After logging into G-Mail account,I should search the mails with specific word and should be able to delete all the searched mails by clicking the drop down(All)

Your help is much appriciated

Answer (score -2):

1. Launch browser using selenium webdriver
   2.navigate to http://gmail.com
2. Input username and password
3. Click on submit button.